# Can´t read some XML files?

Tags: c#, xml, linq, parsing, object

I try to make a XML parser from Vector CANAlyzer xml file. This code work on other xml files but not on this one. Please what in have I miss in the xml standard.

I whant to parse `Network` and `Nodes`.

```
 XElement xmlDoc = XElement.Load(@"Short.xml");
            var result = from c in xmlDoc.Descendants("Network")
                         select new Network()
                       {
                           Network_DB_id = int.Parse(c.Attribute("DB_ID").Value),
                           Name = (string)c.Element("Name").Value,
                           ListNode = from f in c.Descendants("Node")
                                      select new Node()
                                      {
                                          Node_DB_id = int.Parse(f.Attribute("DB_ID").Value),
                                          Name = (string)f.Element("Name").Value,
                                      }
                       };
            return result.ToList();

 public class Network
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public int Network_DB_id { get; set; }
        public IEnumerable<Node> ListNode { get; set; }
    }
    public class Node
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public int Node_DB_id { get; set; }

        public IEnumerable<Message> ListTXMessage { get; set; }
        public IEnumerable<Message> ListRXMessage { get; set; }

    }
```

XML File:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes" ?>
  <Network DB_ID="-4095">
      <Name>SPACE4000</Name>
      <Attribute>
        <Name>BusType</Name>
        <Value>CAN</Value>
      </Attribute>
      <Node DB_ID="4">
        <Name>Space</Name>
        <TxMessage  DB_ID="88">
          <Name>ST_status_1</Name>
      <ID>0x520</ID>
      <Frametype>CAN Standard</Frametype>
      <DLC>8</DLC>
      <Comment></Comment>
      <Signal DB_ID="701">
        <Name>oil2</Name>
        <Bitposition>2</Bitposition>
        <Bitsize>1</Bitsize>
        <Byteorder>Intel</Byteorder>
        <Valuetype>Unsigned</Valuetype>
        <Factor>1</Factor>
        <Offset>0</Offset>
        <Minimum>0</Minimum>
        <Maximum>0</Maximum>
        <Unit></Unit>
        <Comment></Comment>
      </Signal>
    </TxMessage>
  </Node>
</Network>
```

Comment: You have an "}" sign in the end of XML

Comment: Ok I see.. it´s not in the oridignal xml file, just missed that when I post the question.

Answer (score 0):

There's no need to cast and call value i.e. `(string)x.Element("foo").Value` like you're doing in some places. Same goes for the `int.Parse(x.Element("foo").Value)` calls. I coded the example below assuming there could be multiple networks in the XML file, but I doubt it considering Network is the root element. If there is only one network, consider refactoring to reflect that.

```
var xdoc = XDocument.Load("short.xml");

var networks = xdoc.Elements("Network").Select(x => new Network
{
    Network_DB_id = (int)x.Attribute("DB_ID"),
    Name = (string)x.Element("Name"),
    ListNode = x.Elements("Node").Select(n => new Node
    {
        Name = (string)n.Element("Name"),
        Node_DB_id = (int)n.Attribute("DB_ID"),

        // etc.
    })  
});
```